# android string resource vs application size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-resources

Is there a cost to using the android string.xml resources? If I want to keep my application size down, which of the following is better

1. Declare my string literals within the layout files, as in `<TextView android:text="Hello">`
2. Use only one string file to store all strings as resources, as in `strings.xml`
3. Use one string file per activity (so to speak), as in `strings_activity_hello.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no cost as far as I know, and these are two major benefits that I know of:

1. If you use the same string in multiple layouts or classes, you can change it in strings.xml and it will be updated everywhere (you'll never forget to change it somewhere).
2. You can give people the strings.xml for translation, and create files like strings-es.xml (for Spanish) that Android will use for automatically displaying a translated version of your app based on the device's default language.

I'm sure it affects compilation time but I think the SDK combines and optimizes all of your strings somewhere in the actual APK.

Comment: I am aware of all the benefits. But I inherited a codebase that uses the first option. So I figure there must be some advantages that they know about, which I don't know of. So if nobody else in the community disagrees with you, I am accepting your answer. Thank you for helping.

Comment: could you improve your answer by adding any reference to the statement: "there's no cost" plx ;-) i'm just curious about what happens during/after compiling - are there static java classes that replace the R. class? @CoteMounyo the benifit of #1 is _lazyness_ and faster prototyping

Comment: It just makes everything easier, makes the code easier to manage, and how Google designed the SDK to work (which is why they give you warnings when you hardcode strings). But yeah as far as I know there's really no downside to it.

Comment: yeah, i'm totally with you about the benefits and i know that lint in the adt/android studio always warns about strings that are not ressource, but i'm not quite sure, how these ressources are managed in runtime and if there's really no cost (and yes: useless micro-optimization even if there would be a millisecond every now and then)

Comment: IMHO, use #3 when the app is a really "big" app, i've seen string.xml very very long and tedious even to open it and check for any string ;), otherwise use #2, #1 discarted because of what is being explained in this answer.

Comment: Oh yeah I know what you mean